# Geolocation error for ionic app is work on browser but not work on android mobile

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, ionic-framework

i am developing a map based project in which app tries for geolocation of user, if GPS not enable it shows an error message. the code will work properly on browser. but when i use this app on phone it will not working.[image]

```
cede is here:-
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
               marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                    icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
                    draggable:true,
                    map: map,
                    title: "My Location"
                });
               console.log(marker.getPosition());
               console.log(marker.getPosition().A);
               console.log(marker.getPosition().F);
                infoWindow.setContent('<div><strong>'+ "You are here!!" + '</strong><br>');
         infoWindow.open(map, marker);
             },
             function onError(error){
                     $ionicPopup.alert({
                                             title: 'Alert',
                                            template: 'Please Turn on your GPS and come back'});
             });
```

Comment: Did you make a clean installation of the plugin ?  
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html

Comment: yse i m use cordova map plugin in my project.

Answer (score 0):

at last i have found solution of it...i have add {maximumAge:60000,timeout:3000,enableHighAccuracy:true} to my code

```
     function onError(error){
                              $ionicPopup.alert({
                              title: 'Alert',
                              template: 'Please Turn on your GPS and come back'});
                             }
                             {maximumAge:60000,timeout:3000,enableHighAccuracy:true});
```